# Laravel how to loop through array in controller and combine relationship

Tags: php, laravel

In my `laravel`-application I have a `blogs`- and an `author`-table. On the index page, where you see all published blog posts, I want the authors name to appear. So I tried to do this:

```
public function index()
{

    $blogs = Blog::where("publishes_on", "<=", Carbon::now())
        ->orderBy('publishes_on', 'desc')
        ->published()
        ->get();

    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        $author = Author::where('id', $blog->author_id)->get();
    }

    return view('app.blog.index', compact('blogs', 'author'));
}
```

For some reason I do not know, this gives me the last added author to my application and on each post, the name of that author is displayed on all posts.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to wire a ```Blog belongs to Author``` relationship and get the author`s details via that relationship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blog model add `author` relation

```
public function author()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
}
```

In controller

```
$blogs = Blog::where("publishes_on", "<=", Carbon::now())
    ->orderBy('publishes_on', 'desc')
    ->published()
    ->with('author:id,name')
    ->get();
```

In view you can use

```
@foreach($blogs  as $blog)
    // blog related data 
    Author: {{ $blog->author->name ?? '' }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Add the belongsTo relationship in the Blog model, just in case OP's missing that

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

No need for the `foreach` loop

```php
Blog::with('author')->where( [...]`
```

In your view

```php
$blog->author->name
```

Make sure you define `author()` as a relationship on the `Blog` model:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

e.g.

```php
class Blog {
    function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer too!